# Android SDK not saying that components installed right after a successful installation

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

[Android Studio 3.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXrJo.jpg)

[C:\Android\sdk\platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrCu5.png)

I have already installed the components and the android-28 and android-27 API but in Android Studio it still not showing up as installed and because of it, I have problems with Building the project using Gradle.

Comment: Is the SDK path give in AS correct?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.

I have transferred the SDK folder from C:\Users\user\AppData\local\ directly to C:\Android\sdk

I have the local files downloaded successfully when I installed the API using Android Studio SDK Manager. It said installed but not showing up as installed within Android Studio.

Comment: Hmm, I understand, did you try closing AS and turning it on again?

Comment: I have re-installed AS. Checked the SDK folder and platforms are still there installed correctly. But when I checked SDK Manager, still says "Not Installed". I have been finding a solution for this problem for 3 days now. Can't seem to find where I went wrong.